# Can a permission of the app remains after the app was uninstalled?

Tags: android, permissions, backup, uninstallation, android-8.0-oreo

I'm installing an app from the Google play store.
It asks me for the camera access and I'm allowing it.

Then I'm uninstalling the app.

- Will the camera permission remain?
- Will it ask me for the camera permission again when I'm reinstalling it?

Comment: no it will not remain , next time you install app , it will again ask those required permissions.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm uninstalling the app.
>    Will the camera permission remain?

**NO**

> Will it ask me for the camera permission again when I'm reinstalling it?

**YES**